# Liquibase create columns of other type

Tags: java, liquibase

I created a changelog for quite simple table:

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="01" author="me">
        <createTable tableName="folders" remarks="Folders">
            <column name="id" type="uuid">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="last_edited" type="datetime">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="folder_type" type="varchar(10)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

After table has created I see that column `id` has type `varchar(255)` instead of `uuid` and column `folder_type` has type `int4` instead of `varchar(10)`. Why? How I can create columns with required types? I'm working with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Liquibase will convert some types for cross-database reasons, but it shouldn't be converting either of those types on postgresql. If you run `liquibase update-sql` to see what SQL it's actually running, is it sending it to the database as wrong types as part of that changeSet executing?

Comment: It sending correct types but create nothing.

Comment: I found a reason: this table has created twice - by liquibase and by EclipseLink. It was beacuse I forgot to set the `DDL_GENERATION` to `none` in the EclipseLink's configuration.